# javax.ws.rs.client.AsyncInvoker.get() fails with generic callback implementation

Tags: java, resteasy

Trying to make an async `.get()` request with `javax.ws.rs.client.Client` like this:

```
client.target("http://localhost:8080")
        .path("/sample")
        .request()
        .async()
        .get(new GenericCallback<String>());
```

where `GenericCallback` looks like this

```
public final class GenericCallback<T> implements InvocationCallback<T>{
    @Override
    public void completed(T t) {
    }

    @Override
    public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
    }
}
```

And getting this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type must not be null
    at javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType.<init>(GenericType.java:156)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.submit(ClientInvocation.java:530)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.AsynchronousInvoke.get(AsynchronousInvoke.java:52)
```

Looks like `org.jboss.resteasy.util.Types#getActualTypeArgumentsOfAnInterface` fails to get a correct generic type for the InvocationCallback.

Wrote this example to check

```
import org.jboss.resteasy.util.Types;

import javax.ws.rs.client.InvocationCallback;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class GetTypeMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printTypesForCallback(new InvocationCallback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void completed(String result) {
            }

            @Override
            public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
            }
        });

        printTypesForCallback(new TypedCallback());
        printTypesForCallback(new GenericCallback<String>());
    }

    private static void printTypesForCallback(InvocationCallback<?> callback) {
        final Type[] types = Types.getActualTypeArgumentsOfAnInterface(callback.getClass(), InvocationCallback.class);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(types));
    }

    private static final class TypedCallback implements InvocationCallback<String> {
        @Override
        public void completed(String result) {
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
        }
    }

    private static final class GenericCallback<T> implements InvocationCallback<T> {
        @Override
        public void completed(T result) {
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable throwable) {
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[class java.lang.String]
[class java.lang.String]
[null]
```

as expected.

Is there any workaround to use generic class that implements `InvocationCallback`?

**UPD**. I use latest versions of `javax.ws.rs-api` and `resteasy-jaxrs`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

**UPD 2**. Updated `GenericCallback` to be an interface

```
public interface GenericCallback<T> extends InvocationCallback<T> {
    @Override
    default void completed(T result) {
    }

    @Override
    default void failed(Throwable throwable) {
    }
}
```

And this works

```
printTypesForCallback(new GenericCallback<String>() {});
```

prints `[class java.lang.String]`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to define generic callback as 
`GenericCallback  implements InvocationCallback<Object>` ?

Comment: No, why would i want to do that? It won't work fo anything but `Object`

Comment: But you want generic functionality, right? How are you going to implement generic functionality without knowing the base type? And the max base type in hierarchy you know is Object.

Comment: BTW, it will work for everything which is Object. And if you insist to have it generic and not have implementation depends on type, Object is the only choice you have.